# " on the example of the Equation" or "using the Equation as an example"

Tags: sentence-structure, terminology

Which of the following is more correct?

> "we show our results on the example of the Duffing equation"

or

> "we show our results using the Duffing equation as an example"

I am very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is arguably incorrect: the verb "show" does not usuallt take "on" as a preposition. This sentence may be understood, but it's not eloquent writing.

The second sentence is correct and eloquent.